# "Unable to open company file" message returned (Sage 50 Canada)

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, vb6-migration, sage50

We're developing a COM-aware .Net assembly that is used in a legacy VB6 app and keep getting the above message when opening a connection via `SDKInstanceManager.Instance.OpenDatabase`. When we call our method from inside another .Net assembly this does not happen, the call to open works fine. Below is the class we use:

```
[ComVisible(true)]

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyClass_ThreadedEvents))]
[Guid("A8F518D8-6446-11E2-BC88-724F6188709B")]
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{    
    public string OpenConnection()
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            retVal = "OpenConnection|@@|*NOERROR*|@@|*ALLOK*|@@||@@|";

            string conInstallFolder = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Simply Accounting\2017\Samdata\Pro";
            string conCompany = "Universl";
            string conUserName = "sysadmin";
            string conPassword = "12345";
            string conVersName = "Sage 50 Accounts";
            string conVersNumber = "2017";
            string conVersCountry = "Canada";

            bool allok = SDKInstanceManager.Instance.OpenDatabase(conInstallFolder + @"\" + conCompany + ".SAI", conUserName, conPassword, true,
                conVersName + " " + conVersNumber + " " + conVersCountry, "SASDK", 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = "OpenConnection|@@|*ERROR*|@@|" + ex.Message;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

My VB6 code:

```
    Private Function RunTestTasks()

      Dim MyClass As New MyDLL.MyClass
      Dim retval As String
    
      retval = MyClass.OpenConnection()
    
      Call MyClass.CloseConnection
        
      Set MyClass = Nothing

    End Function
```

The .Net assembly only references `Sage_SA.SDK`, `Sage_SA.Domain` and `Sage_SA.Domain.Utility` and targets x86. No instances of Sage or app is accessing the company file. The VB6 code runs as Windows administrator.

Is there anything we're missing? We're stuck and would like to fix this issue. Many thanks.

Please note this has also been posted on the Sage Canada Community forum.

Comment: When called from VB6, its definitely hitting the correct instance of your C# code? eg if you set a breakpoint in the IDE it will be hit?  If it were calling some other out of data assembly that could be a problem.

Comment: It is being hit.

Comment: If I use a unc path I seem to be able to go further but now get Could not load file or assembly 'Sage_SA.Work. I tried putting this file into GAC by registering it using gacutil and not doing so but build the .Net assembly with this file as reference but the error persists in both scenarios. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The Work assembly is in GAC_32 after I register it but VB6 still complains it is missing:

Could not load file or assembly 'Sage_SA.Work, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=04796331da23c125' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What bare-minimum assemblies do I need to register for this to work?

Comment: We thought using UNC naming for the path to the sample cpy worked but it's seems it no longer does. We're stumped.

Comment: You might try using Process Monitor to watch the running program and see what its doing in terms of filesystem access - both to watch DLL/assembly loads but also the sample data files. That often can provide a useful clue.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: We reg'd all the Sage dll that come with the SDK to GAC, rebooted and it seems to connect but we will test more fully this week